# convert pydantic dataclass with extra arguments to dict

Tags: python, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I want to convert a pydantic dataclass to a dict but the method I'm using doesn't work (using python 3.8.10 and pydantic==1.10.8)

```py
import dataclasses

import pydantic


class configExtraArgsAllow:
    extra = pydantic.Extra.allow


@pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass(config=configExtraArgsAllow)
class MyDataModel:
    foo: int


data = {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2,
}

dc = MyDataModel.__pydantic_model__.parse_obj(data)

assert dc.bar == 2

dc_as_dict = dataclasses.asdict(dc)
```

It results in

```
    dc_as_dict = dataclasses.asdict(dc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/dataclasses.py", line 1072, in asdict
    raise TypeError("asdict() should be called on dataclass instances")
TypeError: asdict() should be called on dataclass instances
```

The method above works for pydantic dataclass without extra arguments though.
Is there any other way to convert the pydantic dataclass into a dict when extra arguments are 'allowed'?

Comment: Do you want the extra field to be preserved in the dict output? `MyDataModel.__pydantic_model__ != MyDataModel`. These are not the same classes and cannot be treated as such.

Comment: If you want this not to fail you should do `pydantic.parse_obj_as(MyDataModel, data)`, however, `bar` will not be output by `dataclasses.asdict(dc)`

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. `dc` is **not a Pydantic dataclass** instance. You specifically initialized the underlying **model** with `data`, so `isinstance(dc, BaseModel) is True`. Therefore to get the dictionary representation you can just call `dc.dict()`. Are you sure you even _need_ the Pydantic dataclass variant and not a regular model?

Answer (score 0):

The `__pydantic_model__` attribute of a Pydantic dataclass refrences the underlying `BaseModel` subclass (as documented [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/dataclasses)). So when you call `MyDataModel.__pydantic_model__.parse_obj(data)` you are creating an **instance of that model**, not an instance of the dataclass. Model instances can be easily dumped as dictionaries via the [`dict`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method.

```py
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass as pydantic_dataclass


@pydantic_dataclass(config={"extra": "allow"})
class MyDataModel:
    foo: int


data = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
dc = MyDataModel.__pydantic_model__.parse_obj(data)
print(dc.dict())  # {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```

If you actually want to deal with a Pydantic *dataclass* instance (not a model instance), you have to initialize it as such:

```py
...
data = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
dc = MyDataModel(**data)
```

But the problem is that unlike `BaseModel.dict` the built-in [`dataclasses.asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) method will ignore any "extra" fields. That is because under the hood it first calls the [`dataclasses.fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) function to determine what to dump. ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1079)) And `fields` will only return the actual, *defined* fields of the dataclass, i.e. those contained in the `__dataclass_fields__` dictionary. ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1031)) That dynamically added `bar` attribute will not be one of them.

The best you can do is hack around that with your own implementation of dumping a Pydantic dataclass as a `dict`. Something like this seems to work:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict


def as_dict(obj: object) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    output = {}
    for name, value in obj.__dict__.items():
        if name == "__pydantic_initialised__":
            continue
        if hasattr(type(value), "__pydantic_initialised__"):
            value = as_dict(value)
        output[name] = value
    return output
```

Usage:

```py
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass as pydantic_dataclass

# ... import as_dict


@pydantic_dataclass
class Spam:
    eggs: str


@pydantic_dataclass(config={"extra": "allow"})
class MyDataModel:
    foo: int
    spam: Spam


data = {"foo": 1, "spam": {"eggs": "abc"}, "bar": 2}
dc = MyDataModel(**data)
print(as_dict(dc))
```

Output:

```
{'foo': 1, 'spam': {'eggs': 'abc'}, 'bar': 2}
```